# Hey want a detailed hint about how to solve this question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

The question is:
To prove the following summation for every positive integer n:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = ({n+1}){..if..x =1 }$$
and a similar one which is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} {..if..≠ 1}$$

image of question if u don't understand

Comment: The first one (case $x = 1$) is obvious really. Have you tried plugging in $x=1$ into the LHS and writing out the sum? How many terms do you have, what is the value of each of them? For the second one, have you heard of induction? Alternatively, you can prove it using the proof for the sum of a geometric series. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: did first one and got the answer but for second one it's a bit confusing for me,as you said im searching for induction

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) on geometric series for a proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PhysicsMathsLove said, the first case is trivial, really. For you not to divide by zero in the second case, you have to make that distinction $x \neq 1$. The rest is proof by induction.
First, we prove that (n=1) holds:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k = x^1 + x^0 = x + 1 = \frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1} = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$$.

Now, we go from $n \rightarrow n+1$, assuming our hypothesis holds for $n$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k + x^{n+1} =_{IH} \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} + x^{n+1}$$
$$= \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} + \frac{x^{n+1}(x-1)}{x-1} = \frac{x^{n+1}-1 + x^{n+2}-x^{n+1}}{x-1} = \frac{x^{n+2}-1}{x-1}$$ q.e.d.

Comment: what will happen if n=1 is undefined?

Comment: Then the second case doesn't make any sense at all, which is why you wrote $...if x \neq 1$ in the first place.

Comment: thanks bro for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Hint :
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{k=0}^n x^k \\
&= 1 - x^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x^k\\
&= 1 - x^{n+1} + x S\\
\end{align*}
Solving for $S$ gives you the second equality. First equality is just replacing $x$ with $1$.